Using Implicit Function Theorem to Find a Coordinate System near a point of a level set map
Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth function, $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be a regular value and $S=F^{-1}(c)$ be the embedded submanifold given by the regular level set.
It is well-known that a coordinate system near $p$ is given by $(x^1,\dots,x^{n-m},F_1,\dots,F_m)$, when it results (up to renumbering coordinates) that $\det(\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}_{| p}) \neq 0$, with $i=1,\dots,m$ and $j=n-m+1,\dots,n$.
Take for instance the case of the unit sphere. Near a point in the upper hemisphere, $(x,y,x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ serves a local coordinate system (this is an adapted chart).
Now, in the previous example of the sphere, just use the implicit function theorem to write down $z$ as the graph of $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Is it true that
$$
(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})
$$
serves as a local coordinate system near a point of the upper hemisphere?
